# Error using gspread and python-2.7

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, gspread

I'm beginner in using gspread and in Python. My code work well if I use Python 3.5 but does not work using Python 2.7. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mnt/usbhd/RPIProject/prove.py", line 10, in <module>
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 26, in <module>
from oauth2client import crypt
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/crypt.py", line 23, in <module>
from oauth2client import _pure_python_crypt
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/_pure_python_crypt.py", line 24, in <module>
from pyasn1_modules.rfc2459 import Certificate
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1_modules/rfc2459.py", line 20, in <module>
from pyasn1.type import opentype
ImportError: cannot import name opentype
```

can someone tell me more about this problem?

thanks in advances

Best regards

LaPa

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way: open a terminal and write

```
sudo apt-get install python pyasn1-modules
```

after this the script work well by Python 2.7 also.

bye

LaPa